# Reactjs continuous mounting and unmounting

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I got an issue with [react-masonry-css library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-masonry-css)

My cards in mansonry layout keeps mounting and unmounting when I update some props and 
**shouldComponentUpdate** doesn't work also

I checked the code of library i found that some sort of transformation to the cards caused the rerender

```
 itemsInColumns() {
        const currentColumnCount = this.state.columnCount;
        const itemsInColumns = new Array(currentColumnCount);

        // Force children to be handled as an array
        const items = [].concat(this.props.children|| []);

        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            const columnIndex = i % currentColumnCount;

            if (!itemsInColumns[columnIndex]) {
                itemsInColumns[columnIndex] = [];
            }

            itemsInColumns[columnIndex].push(items[i]);
        }

        return itemsInColumns;
    }
```

and in the render he is displaying the array

```
const childrenInColumns = this.itemsInColumns();

return childrenInColumns.map((items, i) => {
          return <div
            key={i}
          >
            {items}
          </div>;
```

Why does this is causing  mounting and unmounting ? 
And How can I change this code to ovoid this bad performance

Comment: I think it might be because everytime your state changes, your component is re-rendered and so is its return which could be causing a bad loop. Could you try returning a blank element and inside that render the children? Something like 
`return <div>{children .map(i => {i}) }</div>`. Let's see if this helps.

Comment: yes that doesn't cause a problem but when I loop on childrenInColumns array it become a hell of render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the cause of continuous mounting and unmounting

I was changing the number of columns of masonry layout and react was continuously constructing the layout with cards **When a card moves from a column to another column it unmount and mount**

for that i did put a constant number of columns and the problem was solved